# Add to cart after event in magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer

I have created add to cart before the event it's working fine. But I want to the observer after add to cart please tell me how to do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
        <observer name="cart_eventbefore_observer_cartbefore" instance="Cart\Eventbefore\Observer\Cartbefore" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the **checkout_cart_add_product_complete** event, which fires after the product added to cart successfully.

> events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete"> 
      <observer name="after_add_to_cart" instance="YourObserverFile" /> 
   </event>
</config>
```

Answer (score 6):

`checkout_cart_product_add_after` worked for me.

Here are the events fired for checkout cart:

```
checkout_cart_add_product_complete
checkout_cart_update_item_complete
checkout_cart_product_add_after
checkout_cart_update_items_before
checkout_cart_update_items_after
checkout_cart_save_before
checkout_cart_save_after
checkout_cart_product_update_after
```

https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento-2.2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/