# Observer after product is added to cart

Tags: cart, event-observer, addtocart, magento2.2.4

what is the name of the event that I can trigger after adding a product to the cart ?

I need this :

1. The customer adds a product to his cart
2. Intercept the event
3. thanks to the result of and API, add some product for free to the cart

Comment: Please specify magento version?

Comment: I have the version 2.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event name is checkout_cart_add_product_complete

Comment: I found this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213754/add-to-cart-after-event-in-magento2 which one is the best ?

Comment: If you want trigger just after add to cart you can also use : checkout_cart_product_add_after. By the way we suggest checkout_cart_add_product_complete event.

Comment: Can you please give an example code for  checkout_cart_add_product_complete event