# Check minicart successfully added product

Tags: magento2, javascript, addtocart

I have 1 more javascript file, now I want after adding a product to the cart successfully, I want to write an event. Now I want to know how to check when add to cart is successful to execute the next event in my javascript file

Comment: In this case, you have to use the Observer.
Please check this URL.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213754/add-to-cart-after-event-in-magento2

Comment: I mean use it entirely in javascript, when add to cart successfully, i will call another function

Answer (score 0):

To check if add to cart is successful then add your event, you can use customerData to `subscribe` to `customerData.get('cart')` and check **summary count**.

To do this, take the following steps:

Step 1: Declare `catalog-add-to-cart-mixin` config in `requirejs-config.js`.

- File path: app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
- Content:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'VendorName_ModuleName/js/catalog-add-to-cart': {
                'VendorName_ModuleName/js/catalog-add-to-cart-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Step 2: Create `catalog-add-to-cart-mixin.js` file.

- File path: app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart-mixin.js
- Content:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    var catalogAddToCartWidgetMixin = {
        /** @inheritdoc */
        _create: function () {
            this._super();
            this._doSomethingAfterAddedProductToCart();
        },

        _doSomethingAfterAddedProductToCart: function () {
            var cartData = customerData.get('cart');
            var currentCount = cartData()['summary_count'];

            cartData.subscribe(function () {
                if (currentCount !== undefined) {
                    if (cartData()['summary_count'] > currentCount) {
                        // do something here
                        console.log('Added a product to cart');
                    }
                    currentCount = cartData()['summary_count'];
                }
            });
        }
    };

    return function (targetWidget) {
        $.widget('mage.catalogAddToCart', targetWidget, catalogAddToCartWidgetMixin);

        return $.mage.catalogAddToCart;
    };
});
```

Step 3: Re-deploy static content

You're done.